# Chrome no longer shows files under Network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I try to preview the traffic in my Network tab it no longer shows.  It used to before I upgraded it.

I have version Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the filter icon in your screenshot, you might note that it is red, indicating that there is an active filter being applied to the Network Pane request list.  The two checkboxes "Has blocked cookies" and "Blocked Requests" are both checked in your UI in the screenshot-- this means that the request list will only display requests that were blocked **and** that have blocked cookies.  If you uncheck those two checkboxes I believe you will see the complete, unfiltered request list.

Comment: Wow, you nailed it.  Thanks